# How to calculate a number of async processes?

Tags: c#, process

I have an process that will take 30ms. I want to fire it one million times. Every 1ms I fire a process. How many `ms` is needed to finish all processes?

**Update**

I have a windows form with this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private AsyncTimer timer;
    private List<int> grades = new List<int>();
    public Form1()
    {
        timer = new AsyncTimer();
        timer.OnTimerTick += new AsyncTimer.TimerCallbackDel(Syncer);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        timer.StartTimer("1");
        watch.Stop();
        string processTime = watch.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString();
    }
    private void Syncer()
    {
        grades.Add(DoTast());
    }
    public static int DoTast()
    {
        byte[] source = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Kalimba.mp3");
        byte[] input = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3");
        int i = 0;
        int grade = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (source[i] == input[i])
            {
                grade++;
            }
        }
        return grade;
    }
}
```

And this is `AsyncTimer` class:

```
class AsyncTimer
{
    private Timer timer1;
    public delegate void TimerCallbackDel();
    public event TimerCallbackDel OnTimerTick;
    private void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        if (OnTimerTick != null)
        OnTimerTick();
    }
    public void StartTimer(string interval)
    {
        timer1 = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, Int32.Parse(interval) * 1);
    }
}
```

Every 1ms I start a new task that will compare two arrays and it needs 30ms to do it. Now how long it needs to fire 1 million times?

Comment: I doubt that your process still takes 30ms when you have a million of them. furthermore what do you mean by process, a thread or a real process?

Comment: It could not be known from the information given. Even in a real scenario with real code on a real set of cores, the best answer would be 'try it and time it'.

Comment: I have updated the question friends.

Comment: Hmmmm sure about the 30 ms? (Int32.Parse(interval) * 1000  would result in it being seconds not milliseconds

Comment: @Thomas I update the question. It will be run every 1ms now.

Comment: kk. for your question not sure how long but presumably way longer as soon as the processses begin to stack up......if it runs at all then. First the hundreds of "simultaneously" processes slow down each other and second I THINK there is also a limit (imposed by the OS) as to how many threads / processes can exist at a given time (not 100% on that though).

Comment: I like your comments Thomas and Martin. Please provide it as an answer so I can vote or accept them.

Comment: tnx but I don't think mine can be seen as an answer as I'm not sure about the OS limitations themselves. And the other part is better stated by martin there. Thus mine is really more a comment than what I would expect as being put into an answer.

Comment: I have deleted my comment because it contained wrong information and instead provided an answer that hopefully is more correct.

Comment: @Thomas Yes,you are right. But I thought we could discuss more on OS limitation. Maybe I should write another question. Any way, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that your statement about starting a new task every 1 ms and that each task will complete after exactly 30 ms you can see that there will be at most 30 concurrent tasks executing. The execution time of all the tasks will be

```
1,000,000 x 1 ms + 30 ms = 1,000,030 ms ~ 16.7 minutes
```

Actually executing the code may lead to a different result because there might be a longer delay between each task.

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer.Actually it is about 29ms exactly. And this result is in a PC with 2 cores CPU. I assumed that it will be run in 4 or 5 servers and each server process 1/4 of the processes and I assumed that it will take 30ms in this situation(because of async processes). So how do you think about my approximation?

Comment: @HamidReza: The 30 ms (or 29 ms) does not really matter. As long as the tasks are able to complete fast (and 30 ms is fast) it is the interval between starting tasks that matter. Starting 1 million tasks with an interval of 1 ms will take 1 million milliseconds or around a quarter of an hour. If on the other hand starting the tasks at a very high rate (and 1 ms delay is a high rate) overwhelms the computer you get a long queue of tasks waiting to execute and the total execution time may grow far beyond a quarter of an hour. You will have to measure this on a real system.

Comment: Bad news. I will research more and test it. Thanks a lot.